# What URL patterns should I have for a multi-page signup form (using Django)?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-urls

First Post, so forgive any noob-iness -- I'm trying to create a multi-page product sign-up form.  I can get the form to display and the submit button, but I can't find any examples of URL patterns for my urls.py file. I found another similar question with the following suggestions:

"You need to write a view to handle your request.(did that) You need to edit urls.py to map your quiz url to the function in views.py (trying, but failing). So when a request with that quiz url comes Django applies that view function.

When I Redirect the user to the new url is the problem. I can't seem to find an example of what the next pattern should be. Here's my urls.py code (index.html and details.html are my templates so far):

```
url(r'^signup/$', 'signup.views.select_product', name='select_product'),
url(r'^signup/(?P<product_id>\d+)/$', 'signup.views.subscriber_signup', name='subscriber_signup'),
    #...
```

Here's my view code:

```
def select_product(request):
    title = "get yourself an e-edition. wurd."
    pform = ProductForm(request.POST)  
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        pform = ProductForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if pform.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
        # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
        # ...
            return HttpResponseRedirect('signup/index.html') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = ProductForm() # An unbound form
    return render_to_response('signup/index.html', {'title': title, 'pform': pform}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def subscriber_signup(request, product_id):
    signup = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    title = "get yourself an e-edition. wurd."
    sform = SubscriberForm(request.POST)  
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        sform = SubscriberForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if sform.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
        # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
        # ...
            return HttpResponseRedirect('signup/detail.html') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        sform = SubscriberForm() # An unbound form
    return render_to_response('signup/detail.html', {'title': title, 'sform': sform, 'signup': signup,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Is `signup` the name of your Django app?

Comment: Is 'signup/index.html' inside `return HttpResponseRedirect('signup/index.html')` the URL path or just the name of the template file? If its a URL path, make sure it related to root, just like '/signup/index.html'. Even better, use something like reverse('signup_index') and, in urls.py `url(r'^signup/$', 'signup.views.index', name='sign_index')`

Comment: signup is the name of the app, index.html is the name of the template for the first page of the signup form.  And in my URLS.py I have your example, but it's signup.views.select_product and name='select product'  Now my problem is what should the next URL pattern be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or use [Django's form wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) which was designed for this.

Answer (score 0):

so part of the problem was I was using the (User) model in my Subscriber class, which the SubscriberForm was based.  I ditched that and made a form based on a normal class with the objects defined individually.

Here's the URL patterns that eventually worked.

```
url(r'^signup/$', 'signup.views.select_product', name='select_product'),
url(r'^signup/(?P<product_id>\d+)/$', 'signup.views.subscriber_signup', name='subscriber_signup'), 
url(r'^signup/(?P<product_id>\d+)/thankyou/$', 'signup.views.thankyou', name='thankyou'),
```

thanks for the responses.

Anthony